# What are the various metrics for Oracle Cloud Compute VM? What is the REST API for fetching all the metrics?

Tags: rest, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oci-java-sdk

Any API sample is available with request and response? I have went through oracle cloud documentation, there are no samples only rest end point is available.

Comment: VM's are measured in terms of health, performance and capacity.

Comment: There are a few examples and request/response types [on these websites](https://docs.cloud.oracle.com/iaas/api/#/en/monitoring/20180401/Metric/ListMetrics). Depending on what exactly you need storage, monitoring, health checks and the core services should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examples of using the APIs for fetching Metrics can be found here:

- [MonitoringMetricListExample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/MonitoringMetricListExample.java)
- [MonitoringMetricSummarizeExample.java](https://github.com/oracle/oci-java-sdk/blob/master/bmc-examples/src/main/java/MonitoringMetricSummarizeExample.java)

Comment: Thanks for the input [Joe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102677/joe).

Comment: fyi Karthik - for answers that are helpful, it is best to upvote them, as karma is what motivates folks to respond to your questions. If an answer is "the answer" to your question, it should also be marked as "answer" by you. This will make it easier for others with the same question in the future to find the answer if they happen to have the same question. Would you mind going through your questions from the last few days and upvoting / marking things as answer, as makes sense for the answers you've been provided?

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a sample (Python preferable) for monitoring CPU and Memory instance use. Any suggestion?